# Javascript remove last item in stack trace string

Tags: javascript, string, stack-trace

I am creating a Javascript logger, in which, on error messages, I am also adding the stack trace like this:

```
function logMessage(logMessage) 
{
  let stackTrace = new Error().stack;
  logMessage.stackTrace = stackTrace;
  ...
}
```

This gives me the stack trace, but it also obviously adds the method of `logMessage` itself as the last item on the stack...

How can I remove the last trace so I'll only see the trace up until the point that the `logMessage` was called, but without the `logMessage` itself?

Comment: `Error.stack` is a string containing a list of lines for each function, all lines starts with `    at `, you can probably use a `Regular Expression` to convert the stack by removing the first occurence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do it is really simple since the stack we are getting is a string divided by `\n`, in this format:

```
ERROR \n
at ... \n
at ... \n
```

so all we need to do is:

```
let stackTrace = new Error().stack;   //get the stack trace string
let arr = stackTrace.split("\n");     //create an array with all lines
arr.splice(1,1);                      //remove the second line (first line after "ERROR")
stackTrace = arr.join("\n");          //join array back to a string
```

Answer (score 0):

Stack trace returns a multiline string starting with the error message and then all lines starting with `at {function name/position}`;

You can simply change the multiline string and bypassing the first occurence of `at {function name/position}` with `split`, `filter` and `join`

```js
stackTrace.split('\n').filter(function(line, index) { return index !== 1 }).join('\n');
```

**See snippet example**

```js
function deepFunctionStack() {
  return new Error().stack;
}

function layer1Function() {
  return deepFunctionStack();
}

function topLayerFunction() {
  return layer1Function();
}

var originalStack = topLayerFunction();
var formattedStack = originalStack.split('\n').filter(function(line, index) { return index !== 1 }).join('\n');
document.write('Original Stack:');
document.write('<pre>' + originalStack + '</pre>');

document.write('Formatted Stack:');
document.write('<pre>' + formattedStack + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an additional version which handles the differences between Firefox, Chrome, & IE stack traces. It will remove the initial "ERROR" line from Chrome and IE. It is also significantly faster than other versions listed here.

```
// stack: string - call stack string
// levels: int - number of levels to remove from the top of the call stack
function trimCallStack(stack, levels) {
    if (stack) {
        const newLineChar = "\n"; // Each line deliminated by '\n'
        const isFirefoxCallStack = stack.indexOf("@") > -1; // If stacktrace contains '@' it is FireFox
        // remove an additional line if browser is NOT FireFox (i.e. Chrome or IE) since those start stack trace with the error name
        // remove N additional lines specified by `levels`
        let iterations = (isFirefoxCallStack ? 0 : 1) + (levels ?? 0);
        let start = 0;
        while(iterations-- && start !== -1) {
            start = stack.indexOf(newLineChar, start + 1);
        }
        
        stack = start !== -1 ? stack.substring(start + 1) : ""; // start === -1 if removing more lines than exist, so return "" in that case
    }

    return stack || "";
}
```

Examples of stack traces from FireFox and Chrome/IE:

Chrome/IE stacktrace:

```
Error: fail
    at test (<anonymous>:2:8)
    at test1 (<anonymous>:5:5)
    at test2 (<anonymous>:8:5)
    at test3 (<anonymous>:11:5)
    at <anonymous>:1:5
```

Firefox stacktrace:

```
test@debugger eval code:2:8
test1@debugger eval code:5:5
test2@debugger eval code:8:5
test3@debugger eval code:11:5
@debugger eval code:1:5
```

After using the provided function:

Chrome/IE stacktrace:

```
    at test (<anonymous>:2:8)
    at test1 (<anonymous>:5:5)
    at test2 (<anonymous>:8:5)
    at test3 (<anonymous>:11:5)
    at <anonymous>:1:5
```

Firefox stacktrace:

```
test@debugger eval code:2:8
test1@debugger eval code:5:5
test2@debugger eval code:8:5
test3@debugger eval code:11:5
@debugger eval code:1:5
```

Answer (score 0):

I previously used this question/answer to remove an item from my stacktrace to send to **Sentry**.

But wanted to point out to those who are doing this for **Sentry** that this **isn't needed**. Sentry has a way to de-prioritize the stacktrace from an error

For example if the function we wanted to remove was `logMessage` we would add

`stack.function:captureError          -app -group`

https://docs.sentry.io/product/data-management-settings/event-grouping/stack-trace-rules/